# How to replace spaces with "_" in the data between brackets using shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I want to replace spaces from data which are written in brackets using shell script.
my input line is

> 2012-05-21 06:37:16 M NumberOfHwEntitiesMismatch Cabinet=1
>   (SAU that is not configured detected.)

I want my output to be:

> 2012-05-21 06:37:16 M NumberOfHwEntitiesMismatch Cabinet=1
>   (SAU_that_is_not_configured_detected.)

Please suggest me something....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`, split on "(" and then use `gsub` to replace space with underscore in the second field.

Example:

```
$ awk -F\( '{gsub(" ","_", $2);print $1"("$2}' <<< "2012-05-21 06:37:16 M NumberOfHwEntitiesMismatch Cabinet=1 (SAU that is not configured detected.)"
2012-05-21 06:37:16 M NumberOfHwEntitiesMismatch Cabinet=1 (SAU_that_is_not_configured_detected.)
```

(This assumes that your input has only one set of brackets.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is a great help

Comment: Hi dogbane

Please explain me this command
awk -F\( '{gsub(" ","_", $2);print $1"("$2}'

Comment: Firstly, `-F\(` tells awk to use `(` as a field delimiter. Then the`gsub` function replaces the space character with an underscore in the second field. Finally, the first and second fields are printed out.